# Why won't the command "crontab /tmp/crontab.txt" work when used in an exec command in php?

Tags: php, cron

I'm using the following code:

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'* * * * * NEW_CRON'.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
```

I've tried changing from exec to shell_exec, also tried removing the echo but I can not seem to get the last line of code to work! If i type the crontab command into the terminal it works then but not when I'm trying to use it in php, any thoughts?

Comment: Is the `crontab.txt` populated correctly?

Comment: Yes when I check the file it has the correct text in it as wanted.

Comment: Ok so I've tried this code and it seems to have worked for me. There's obviously nothing that will be printed but the following time you run this the text file will have the additional line.

Comment: Is the `crontab` command interactive? Why don't you capture stdout, stderr and return code?